# Calculating displacement by getting previous position. (C)

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out how do I get previous position from the function that I wrote. I tried to solve it for hours but couldn't make it. Enemy's(N) initial position is (0,0) and every x and y values after that generate randomly. 'O' is my base and it is located in (6,6). The borders are 11x11. The problem is refresh_position function always calculate displacement by getting previus position as '0'. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
void track_machine();
void refresh_position(int *X, int *Y, double *D, double *R);

void main()
{
   track_machine();
}

void track_machine()
{
    int x=0, y=0;
    char op;
    double D, R;
    refresh_position(&x, &y, &D, &R);
    for(int i=1; i<=11; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<=11; j++)
        {
            if(i==x && j==y)
                printf("N ");
            else if(i==6 && j==6)
                printf("O ");
            else
                printf(". ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Enemies X position:%d\nY position:%d\nDisplacement:%f\nDistance to our camp:%f\nCommand waiting...:\n", x, y, D, R);

    scanf(" %c", &op);

    if(op=='R')
        track_machine();
    else if(op=='E')
        main();
    else
        printf("\nERROR!\n");
}

void refresh_position(int *X, int *Y, double *D, double *R)
{
    int x=*X, y=*Y, xD, yD, xR, yR;
    srand(time(0)); 
    while( (*X==0 || *X==6) || (*Y==0 || *Y==6) )
    {
        *X = rand()%11;
        *Y = rand()%11;
    }

    xD=abs(*X-x);
    yD=abs(*Y-y);

    xR=abs(*X-6);
    yR=abs(*Y-6);

    *D = sqrt( (xD*xD) + (yD*yD) );
    *R = sqrt( (xR*xR) + (yR*yR) );

}
```

Comment: Seed `srand(time(0));` should be used in `main()` otherwise it will restart at every function call.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Fixed it thanks but it's not the main problem :(

Comment: I suspect you want `while( !((*X==0 && *Y==0) || (*Y==6 && *Y==6)) )`.  Perhaps other errors too.

Comment: I was wrong since you call main() in one of your options the problem remains, also R and E are the same since calling main() or track_machine() in this instance is the same thing. Another thing you should fix is your main(), it should return int. As for you problem, I'll have to leave it to other users, since I can't test it right now.

Comment: @anastaciu [Another thing you should fix is your main(), it should return int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765907/calculating-displacement-by-getting-previous-position-c#comment107512211_60765907) : Should--> yes.  Required --> No.

Comment: And if in freestanding environment, program startup is completely implementation defined [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1) Many embedded systems, Arduino, TI MSP432, etc.. fall into that basket -- though many have an RTOS available.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think, this is a kind of board game and board positions are numbered from 1 to 11. What I deduce from the `while` loop is, you do not want `*X` & `*Y` be '0' or '6'. However, using mod(11) w/o adding (increment) '1' will never produce a random result '11'. So, you'd better change that loop into a more efficient `do-while`, like;

```
do {
    *X = rand() % 11 + 1;
    *Y = rand() % 11 + 1;
} while((*X == 6) && (*Y == 6));
```

This way, `rand() % 11` will produce a number b/w 0 - 10 (inclusive), then adding '1' will produce a number b/w 1 - 11 (inclusive). You will get rid of checking for '0' values.

2. Addressing your question about the code (tough not sure whether I've understood your question 100%); I think the problem arise from the function `track_machine` having no parameters. Initializing `x` & `y` in `main` and then passing those variables to the function via parameters will solve your issue (of course, if I've understood your question truly).

```
// main should be
int main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    track_machine(x, y);
}

// function decoration should be
void track_machine(int x, int y) {...}

// and your recursive call line should read as
if (op == 'R')
    track_machine(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't describe my problem good enough. Sorry for that but I found what I did wrong. The code prints 11 dots in both x and y direction. My goal was finding the distance between N (which is located randomly each 'R' command in 11x11 area) and O (which is my base located in 6,6) and finding the displacement every time N changes position when I give 'R' command. Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
void track_machine();
void refresh_position(int *X, int *Y, double *D, double *R)

int main()
{
   track_machine();
}
void track_machine()
{
    int x=1, y=1;
    char op;
    double D, R;
    srand(time(0));
    D = 0;
    R = 8.49;
    while(1==1){
        for(int i=1; i<=11; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<=11; j++){
                if(i==x && j==y)
                    printf("N ");
                else if(i==6 && j==6)
                    printf("O ");
                else
                    printf(". ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Enemies X position:%d\nY position:%d\nDisplacement:%f\nDistance to our camp:%f\nCommand waiting...:\n", x, y, D, R);
        scanf(" %c", &op);

        if(op=='R')
            refresh_position(&x, &y, &D, &R);
        else if(op=='E'){
            main();
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("\nERROR!\n");
    }
}

void refresh_position(int *X, int *Y, double *D, double *R)
{
    int x=*X, y=*Y;

    do {
        *X = rand()%11+1;
        *Y = rand()%11+1;   
    } while((*X == 6) || (*Y == 6));

    *D = sqrt( ((*X-x)*(*X-x)) + ((*Y-y)*(*Y-y)) );
    *R = sqrt( ((*X-6)*(*X-6)) + ((*Y-6)*(*Y-6)) );

}
```

I can't use parameters for track_machine because I'm not allowed to :). Every time I give 'R' it refreshes the location of 'N' and calculates new 'D' and 'R' values as long as I don't give 'E' command. Actually it is not the whole code this is just a small part of it. When it returns to main it asks for 'op' to choose other functions in switch case. I hope I explained it enough this time. Thanks for help though!

Comment: About that **while** condition `...} while((*X == 6) || (*Y == 6));` in your code; if you do not want 'N' to be located on row 6 (independent of column) or not to be located on column 6 (independent of row), then it is okay. However, if your aim is to refrain 'N' get located on top of 'O', then your condition should be `...} while((*X == 6) && (*Y == 6));`.